# RadComboBox adding an item to the top

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to add an item to the top of the drop down. I am using ItemTemplates so i am doing the databind and trying to add one at the top that reads

```
[ ] All Profiles
```

I was able to add it, but it is overriding the binding of the actual data, so when i added this now only the `[ ] All profiles` is there but not the real binded data. What am I doing wrong?

By the way i am a newbie in c# :)

Thank you

```
  public void BindData()
{
    myCombo.DataSource = myDbConnection.GetValues();
    myCombo.DataTextField = "Name";
    myCombo.DataValueField = "ID";
    myCombo.DataBind();
    var tempProfiles = new[] { new { Name = "All Profiles", ID = "1" } };
    myCombo.DataSource = tempProfiles;
    myCombo.DataBind();

}

<telerik:RadComboBox ID="myCombo" EmptyMessage="All Types" runat="server" Width="200px">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <div onclick="StopPropagation(event)">
         <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" onclick="onCheckBoxClick(this)"/>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProfile" AssociatedControlID="chk1">
                  <%# Eval("Name") %>
               </asp:Label>
             </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example you're overwriting your DataSourceObject with your 1-item-list.

You should add the item "manually" after your `DataBind` call:

```
 myCombo.Items.Insert(0, 
       new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem { Text = "All Profiles", Value = "1" }
    );
 myCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I tried this but its telling me the following: The best overloaded method match for 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemCollection.Insert(int, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: so, just try: `new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem { `... instead and use the right property names of the RadComboBoxItem

Comment: Ok I tried this and it does show the checkbox and when clicked the string shows "All Profiles" but the problem is that in the ComboBox it shows the checkbox and the label is empty, this label is within an ItemTemplate.. how can I pass the Text for the item templace so that it shows the checkbox and next to it the label? - sorry i am kind of a newbie :)

Posted code above

Comment: You have to set the right properties, I guess they are `Text` and `Value`. I'll research it and edit my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

if you work in Bound mode all data should come from the DataSource.

what I usually do is to add an extra element in the datasource with ID 0 or int.MaxValue depending on the sort order and the position where I want to show it.